# proof monotonicity of integral on simple functions

Tags: real-analysis

If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are simple functions, and $\phi \le \psi$, then $\int_I\phi d\mu \le \int_I\psi d\mu$.

I can use the linearity in this proof, but I don't know whether it helps.

Comment: Try finding an arbitrary function $h=\phi - \psi$ such that $\int_{I}h d \mu \leq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** WLOG chose a partition of $I$ such that
$$\phi = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i \chi_{A_i}, \qquad \psi = \sum_{i=1}^N b_i \chi_{A_i}$$
Where $a_i, b_i$ need not necessarily be distinct. What can you infer from $\phi \le \psi$?